# AngularJS How to implement a breadcrumbs for an entire app with menus

Tags: angularjs, breadcrumbs

Is there any good bread crumbs plugin for angularJS 1.x with detailed introduction?

I find below：

https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb/wiki/Getting-started

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ui-router-breadcrumbs

But it does not show how to use it clearly.I want to make it work in my whole app too.

For the second one, I have seen form [here](https://www.michaelbromley.co.uk/blog/auto-breadcrumbs-with-angular-ui-router/) that

> The directive uses the $state service to generate the breadcrumbs by looking at the current state, and the traversing the state hierarchy to construct an array of breadcrumbs that are then used in an ng-repeat to generate the expected output.

But my situation is used for the whole menus. I have one page with $state name `index.cars`, the other page with $state name `index.phones`, I want to show the bread crumb `cars / phones` when I click a button to redirect me from `cars` to `phones` page.

What is the best plugin to do so?

Comment: If you look at states like a tree of nodes (which Angular-ui-router does), then breadcrumbs are a path through that tree towards the current state. Aren't `index.cars` and `index.phones` siblings? In that case, you'd want a submenu to show as part of the template of the `index` parent state

Comment: @Ruben Helsloot Thank you, In fact, they are two different pages,not siblings, and I just want to show all my redirect routes as a bread crumb.SO, it could show `cars > phones` So I doubut whether the Angular-ui-router  could do it.

Comment: You can always look at `$state.get()` to get a list of all states and construct a breadcrumb like that, but in this case I don't think a breadcrumb would be the best solution. The prefix `index.` implicitly makes `cars` and `phones` sibling states under `index`, as per [uirouter](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/states#nested-states)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I use `angular-breadcrumb` ,refer to

https://github.com/ncuillery/angular-breadcrumb/wiki/API-Reference#state-options

I use `lable` and `parent` ro set page name and its parent state.

```
 $stateProvider.state('index.phones ', {
        url: '/phones ',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
                label: 'Phones ',
                parent: function($scope) {
                    //set `$scope.parentStateName = "index.cars"` in your controller when you redirect from cars to phones
                    return $scope.parentStateName ? $scope.parentStateName : null;
                }
        },
 })
```